# border or image not showing on horizontal scroll in iphone

Tags: html, css

[image]

when i scroll the page horizontally div border on top doesn't show.
here's is CSS and HTML.

please check the attached image also.

```
.top {
    height:28px;
    padding-top:7px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #f7931d;
}

<div class="top"></div>
```

Comment: the div doesn't have a width, so it is impossible to see...

Comment: please provide a link to the page. I don't see any issue in the piece of code.

Comment: yes i did it but it's also not working with width:100%;

Comment: Greattt, Thank You very much Milan Jaric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div width is following screen width since you have some floating objectes inside (probably, its just guess).

you can either do

```
.top {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or to set expected width