# Iphone show border only if is inline

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome

I'm trying put a border on a div with position absolute, over an image, works well on android and desktop browser, but on iphone only works if I put the styles inline, if I put the styles in the css, the border is not showed.

Following this code only the first link shows a border on Chrome/iPhone

**HTML**

```
<div class="w-100" id="infographic-links">
  <a style="border: 5px solid red" href="/link5" id="goals">AAA</a>
  <a href="/link4" id="reach">BBB </a>
  <a href="/link3" id="achieved">CCC </a>
  <a href="/link2" id="webminar">DDD </a>
  <a href="/link1" id="reporting-page">EEE </a>
  <a  href="/link" id="involved">FFF </a> 
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.image-module {
&__full {
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
}

.desktop_image {
display: none;

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  display: block;
}
}

.mobile_image {
display: block;

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  display: none;
}
}

.container-fluid {
position: relative;
}

#infographic-links {
position: absolute;
max-width: 100%;
overflow: visible;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

a {
  border: 5px solid red
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgb(20, 43, 40);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgb(20, 43, 40);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgb(20, 43, 40);
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  }
}

#goals {
  height: 12.5%;
  width: 44.95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.3%;
  left: 16.3%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 17.1%;
    width: 79.8%;
    top: 10.7%;
    left: 10.2%;
  }
}

#reach {
  height: 11.75%;
  width: 33.7%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26.2%;
  left: 16.3%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 7%;
    width: 79.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33.55%;
    left: 10.2%;
  }
}

#achieved {
  height: 11.3%;
  width: 67.4%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44.2%;
  left: 16.3%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 9.3%;
    width: 79.7%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 46.75%;
    left: 10.3%;
  }
}

#webminar {
  height: 17.4%;
  width: 33.7%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.485%;
  left: 16.3%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 11.75%;
    width: 79.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55.48%;
    left: 10.2%;
  }
}

#reporting-page {
  height: 17.4%;
  width: 33.7%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.48%;
  left: 50%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 11.35%;
    width: 79.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 67.8%;
    left: 10.2%;
  }
}

#involved {
  height: 22%;
  width: 67.35%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 73%;
  left: 16.3%;

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    height: 19.45%;
    width: 79.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 79.15%;
    left: 10.2%;
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405532/border-or-image-not-showing-on-horizontal-scroll-in-iphone)

Comment: No, thats not work @anirudh

Comment: Could you show your SCSS? The only thing I can think of is that there's some error in it which the browser is sensing and/or try writing out the SCSS as CSS - I've tried that and can't see a problem.

Comment: I just updated the question showing all the CSS of that file @AHaworth